# How to parse the image as a background app and output as voice in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create a screen reader for android using flutter. My plan is create a screenshot and trigger flutter app whenever user takes screenshot by clicking the screenshot shortcut buttons.

And need to do screen reading from the screenshot.

Don't know how to start. Can anyone please guide me.

Can suggest other environment if flutter doesn't support.

For the clarity, please suggest me the api or library related to convert text to voice..Also image to text. So, I can link both and crete the app. I can see such APIs in python but not in dart.

And please don't close this question if you don't like it. An earlier question of the same was closed by the time an expert in flutter started conversation and he is not allowed to reply because of it.

If you don't like the question, please let others to reply it insted of closing it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you to use Flutter for this project as it's matured enough for handling such interactions.

For converting image to text you can use the library of [tesseract_ocr](https://pub.dev/packages/tesseract_ocr).
For converting text to voice you can use this library of [text to speech](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts).

For making screen readers like [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/lae/accessibility/vision/) please go through this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility#screen-readers).

Comment: Thanks Darsh, I will give a try and reply back